# pm2 - running multiple node.js processes on one CPU

Tags: node.js, unix, process, pm2

I found lot of articles how to scale node.js, all about scaling one thread of node.js app to more processes.

But I need complete opposite thing :)

I need to run on single CPU more cli node.js processes (started via pm2). When I run one process all is fine. When I run second, both processes freezes.

I am running it like this:

`pm2 start -i 1 --name task1 myscript.js -- argument
pm2 start -i 1 --name task2 myscript.js -- argument`

What is the best solution please?

Comment: Why do they freeze? Some error?

Comment: I think it is due to lack CPU pipelines. On local I have 4 CPUs, 2 processes works fine. On other machine I have 1 CPU, one process works fine, when I add second process, all apps in node.js freezes.

Comment: what to do for this? if i want to run two process at same time and one same computer.

Comment: Count of CPU cores = max node processes 

So, in best case, you have to do it yourself.
The only way I have found is to run two asynchronnous functions.


worker1((err) => {
  console.log(err");
}
worker2((err) => {
  console.log(err");
}

(sorry for my formatting, i am writing from a phone)